# Unable to view digitally signed pdf file using pdf.js in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, codeigniter, codeigniter-3, pdf.js

I have an application using angularjs 1.x and codeigniter 3.x. Ran this webapp in chrome as well in firefox and able to view normal pdf but not digitally signed pdf file. Please find the below code which i am using.
html side

```
<a ng-click="openViewer()" style="cursor:pointer;">Digitally_signed.pdf</a>
```

angular js side

```
$scope.finalurl = btoa(BASE_URL+'/pdf_files/Digitally_signed.pdf');
$scope.openViewer = function() {
    var url = BASE_URL + '/web/pdfviewer.html?file=' + $scope.finalurl;
    window.open(url, 'newwindow', config = 'height=700, width=1000, ' +
        'toolbar=no, menubar=no, scrollbars=no, resizable=no, location=no, ' +
        'directories=no, status=no');
}
```

I have followed this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57380989/preview-pdf-file-with-e-signature-in-angular) but didn't work. Also i have attached an output as image what i am getting.

[image]

Could you please help me what code modification required in **pdfjs** lib to view digitally signed pdf file. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

On Github the [Issue #1076](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/issues/1076#issuecomment-3482481) states that the developers off PDF.js has no intention to implement the possibility of opening digital signed pdf files.

You can contribute and push this feature request by participating it so it gets more attention.

Comment: @KJ Yes able to open using adobe reader but using pdfjs to give end user only customized view like don't allow to copy/print/right click, etc

Comment: @KJ Actually pdfjs is being used in app from starting and now we got first time digitally signed pdf so as of now no requirement to verify false signature but just to view the pdf

Comment: @CalligraphVoid Let me go through the thread which you shared

Comment: I have just taken new build of pdfjs but while running using above code, it says Missing Pdf exception. Looks like doesn't support **btoa** conversion. What to modify to run with btoa

Comment: I am also getting Warning: Filter "Crypt" is not supported.

Comment: @KJ I will go through this, I wanted to convey that using old version of pdfjs lib btoa works fine like this *www.myweb.com/web/pdfviewer.html?file=aHR0cDovL2xvY2FsaG9* Where as with new pdfjs lib i need to expose file name like *www.myweb.com/web/pdfviewer.html?file=Digitally_signed.pdf*     Do you have suggestions what to modify to run with btoa, please suggest